# Measuring the equatorial diameter of an ellipsoidal object

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, homography

I'm trying to measure the equatorial diameter of a grape using an image of a bunch of grapes. I can recognize each grape categorized inside bounding boxes with a machine learning algorithm. I can also know the proportion from millimeters/pixel of the image by providing a square next to the bunch of grapes that I already know the size and using OpenCV to measure and recognize it.
My problem is the **depth of the grape**. I've been thinking that maybe can be useful taking two pictures of the bunch of grapes so then I can know the angle of translation with the homographic matrix and match the images with maybe SIFT/SURF/BRIEF/ORB algorithms, but I'm not sure if this will solve my problem.

I appreciate any help!
Thanks

EDIT*
[Image of reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XspVx.jpg)

With a more extensive research, I think that a good idea would be to have an algorithm that can constantly identify the ecuatorial diameter of the grape, so while you move the camera pointing to the bunch of grapes, it can be constantly calculating the diameter. So you move the camera around the grapes and save the different diameters for each grape, so after a while spinning around, the algorithm can save for each grape the biggest value. It's probably highly inefficient. So if someone has a better idea, it's always welcome :).

Comment: is it not safe to assume that the grape is round? If you can measure the width of the grape then that should be the same as its depth. Can you post some pictures illustrating the issue?

Comment: No, it isn't safe :(. Usually they are ellipsoids. If they were spherical the problem would be easier. I will edit the question with the corresponding picture.